# Verify if an NPM package is official

Tags: node.js, npm, open-source, binance

I am developing an app that needs to use Binance API. I found an NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@binance/connector

But I am not sure if it is an official one or created by someone else. What are the criteria to identify a good npm package by good I mean not containing any malicious code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPM package links to a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-node). The GitHub repo *readme* links back to the NPM package. So far so good.

The GitHub repo is published under the [binance](https://github.com/binance/) organization, which has the *verified* tag with comment:

> *We've verified that the organization binance controls the domain: [www.binance.com](http://www.binance.com)*

So assuming that we can trust the GitHub verification process, this particular NPM package is legit and really comes from Binance.

---

General rules of thumb to roughly identify a level of trustworthiness of an NPM package:

- Published by a verified organization.
- Downloads amount. A package with 1k weekly downloads is more likely to be legit, compared to a package with 1-2 downloads a week.
- Size of a community around this package. Look for the number of contributors and, official website, support forum with active users. These are the signs that the package is probably all right.
- If the package is business critical for your case, always do your own due diligence and look through the code.